# anchor tag not working while generating single PDF from Multiple PDF files using mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I have three PDF files. I want to integrate three PDF files into a single PDF file. I have used mPDF library to generate single PDF file from multiple PDF files.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('en', 'A4-L');
$mpdf->SetSourceFile("1.pdf");
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage(1);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
$mpdf->SetSourceFile("2.pdf");
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage(1);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
$mpdf->SetSourceFile("3.pdf");
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage(1);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
$mpdf->Output("output.pdf", "D");
```

When generating a single PDF file, I can not see anchor URL into the text in PDF file.

[Sample PDF File Here](http://simbanic.com/_projects/demo/pdf/1.pdf)

Comment: try it manually and check it works for me

Comment: Can you please explain again?

Comment: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Examples check demo5

Comment: anchor tag working very well in single PDF. but when generating single PDF file from Multiple, then not working. Can you please send me proper link for merge PDF?

Comment: Can you please give me a code for workable anchor tag in merge PDF?